# Flutter non-nullable

Tags: flutter

I have a error  The non-nullable local variable 'firebaseUser' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression

My code

```
if (firebaseUser != null) {
  saveUserInfoToFirestore(firebaseUser).then((value) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => StoreHome());
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
  });
}
```

Comment: The variable `firebaseUser` is probably `late` right? if so, did you assign it to a value before checking if it's null?

Answer (score 0):

Checking a non-nullable variable to be null, is like say to a man with no legs he should run.

I guess you have something like this:

```
User firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

So if you want to check about null, you have to make it nullable first. Doing so with "?" after the typedeclaration.

```
User? firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

For more info:
https://dart.dev/null-safety